# phpmailer not sending variables

Tags: php, variables, phpmailer

I am trying to use phpmailer to send a user's input from an html form

Form is like this

```
<form action="senditpm.php" role="form">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"><br>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">>br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">>br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button btn btn-default">
</form>
```

senditpm.php is like this

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email= $_POST['email'] ;

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();              
$mail->Host = 'xxxxxxxxx';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                               
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxx';                
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';                           
$mail->Port = 25; 

$mail->setFrom('xxx@xxxxs.co.uk', 'xxxxx');
$mail->addAddress('xxx@xxx', 'xxx xxxx'); 
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';


$mail->Body="
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone: $phone <br>"; 

;

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
  }
?>
```

When I complete the form and click Submit, I receive an email like this

Name:

Email:

Phone:

As you can see, the php isn't sending the variables
Please could someone let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<form>` defaults to a GET method if a POST method is not implied and you are using POST arrays.

So change

```
<form action="senditpm.php" role="form">
```

to

```
<form action="senditpm.php" role="form" method="post">
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ayye Fred I'm your **#1 fan**.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes :-) Aahhh gee, thanks. Ohh... stop it; you're making me blush *lol!*

Comment: Alternatively, instead of `$_POST` you can use `$_REQUEST` which contains a merged array of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` superglobals (order defined in php.ini), and then your form will work with either GET or POST.

Comment: Oh lovely another downvote. Thank you, ohhh thank you so much :-) now I have a bit of everything to add to my collection, *woohoo!!!!!* keep 'em comin' boys!!! It just adds to my daily excitement.